# Windows 8 ran in VMware doesn't know it's being run on a laptop

Tags: windows-8, vmware, battery, osx-mountain-lion

I'm running Windows 8 inside VMware Fusion on OS X; everything works fine, except as you can see below, I get no icon for the battery, i.e. Windows 8 doesn't know it's running on a laptop. That has recently become a problem because Windows 8 starts doing maintenance which drains the battery faster. Presumably if it knew it was running on battery it would postpone the maintenance.

[image]

How can I get Windows 8 to recognize the battery?

Comment: This almost has to be a VMware Fusion on Windows 8 driver thing. I assume this worked when the guest OS was Windows 7? If so, then check to see if VMware has newer drivers for Windows 8 yet. They might.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Fusion but on the Windows version of Workstation 9 there is a setting per VM under Settings -> Options -> Power -> "Report battery information to guest". Checking this seems to have the desired effect.

[image: VM Battery setting in VMWare Workstation]

Presumably Fusion has something similar.